# Groups turn Based Game

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm  building a game using  firebase. In that  Game there  are  many  rooms  in which  players  play. The Game is i guess its  called  turn  Based.
Because  only  one player can draw and  the  others  should  guess like a simple  draw  and  guess .
My question is how can  i achieve  that  only One player can draw while the others  guess. 
My idea  was to give  every  player  in the Room a boolean  like `bool  isTurn;` and  if  its  true  the player can  draw. There  always  just can be one true  bool  in each  Room of course.
My  question  is if  it could Work like  this  and if there is  a smarter  way  to handle  this?

Comment: I suggest you try GameDev: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I did a session at I/O 2017 about building a turn-based game with Firebase.  You can offload the state management safely to Cloud Functions for Firebase with a lot less effort than trying to code it up on the client.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWj6dxfN63g

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a state-machine-like approach and use an enumerator populated with the players. For example:

`public enum Turn {
     PLAYER_1, PLAYER_2, PLAYER_3; 
}`

and then increment these as the player's turns change. A boolean would probably work as well, but may be more convoluted than you like.

Answer (score 1):

If something must be unique, I typically model it as a key in the Firebase database. Since keys are guaranteed to be unique in their context, this ensures I can never make a mistake that messes up the uniqueness.

In your case, that could mean that you have a property that contains the UID of the user whose turn it is:

```
games
  $gameid
    playerWhoseTurnItIs: $uid
```

You could combine this with Easton's FSM to ensure you move from player to player in an orderly fashion.